# Setting up wireless transmission between routers

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wifi-configuration

Is it possible to connect two routers via wireless network, without second being a repeater or visible on the network. So that I can connect via cable to second one.
Small diagram:

```
Router1(regular wifi, visible to everyone on the network) )))))wireless))))) Router2 -----wired-----> PC
```

The cable between Routers or Router and the PC is not a option.
The problem is second router I have is some cheap DLINK, and when somebody connects wirelessly to it, he gets very slow connection. But I have PC, that I'm being lazy buying a wireless card/adapter for and I don't really mind mid quality connection.

Answer (score 0):

It's a long and painful process. Use powerline adapters instead. If dlink is compatible with openwrt then install their firmware. You will have a far better router.

Comment: that is not correct

Comment: It's a far better solution than anything that can be made with the hardware mentioned - The powerlines could also create a hard-wired connection to the dlink. The OP also needs a lot more understanding of TCP/IP too.

Comment: @JohnyVegas There is no evidence the OP does not have an adequate understanding of TCP/IP (and indeed the reference to "not a repeater" and the proposed diagram implies a modicum of networking knowledge) and most DLink Ethernet routers (as opposed to for DSL ones) support dd-wrt is common if AP functionality is not built into the model in question. Ethernet over power line is a good idea although it can be hit-and-miss depending on house wiring and is a lot more expensive then an at-hand router.  (I'm not the downvoter)

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly easy to do. You don't actually want a "Router2" because this implies routing which makes it visible. What you want is an AP client (access point client). Many routers have an AP client mode you can turn on.

The only gotcha is that when its an AP Client it won't get an IP address from the main router so you will need to manually set it if you want to be able to access the device!

Comment: So the order will be as followed: 1) Change connection type from 'Dynamic DHCP' to 'Static IP'. 2) Change mode to AP client. Right?

Comment: I'm a little bit confused with amount of configuration options. I have required input fields like: IP, Default Gateway, Primary/Secondary DNS. If I understand it right I should set IP as whatever, Gateway - ip of Router1, and DNS also as ip of Router1. Right?

Comment: Either I do change to static ip or don't, I'm no longer able to access router via wire/wireless connection. It fails while trying to get ip from the router. Probably I do something terribly wrong. Can you at least direct me, what do I need google or so? Thanks

Comment: You would treat the AP like any other machine you assign an IP address to. The IP address should be in the same subnet that the primary router hands out but outside the DHCP range. The subnet and netmask are the same as specified in the main router/other devices, and the gateway is the other routers man address. You need to specify this on the LAN interface.

Comment: DNS can be gateway 1 or anything - it won't be used. Also, if there is the option to, disable the dhcp server on the AP.  You do, of-course need to configure the AP with the SSID and password of the router.